# What is the negation for "$A - B \subseteq C$?"

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I was given an implication to prove, and I need to prove it using an indirect proof via contrapositive. I need to know the negation of this original statement: $A - B \subseteq C$. Presumably, I think it's $A - B \not\subseteq C$, but I'm not certain that $A - B \not\subseteq C$ is correct. The semantic of this statement is quite puzzling. Is it $\forall x \in A$, $\exists x \not\in B$, $\forall x \not\in C$? Does this mean $A - B$ and $C$ are disjoint sets when negated?

Comment: If $x \in A - B$, then $x \in A \wedge x \not\in B$.

Comment: Try it with words... "the set difference of A and B ($A \setminus B$) is a subset of C". Its negation will be: "the set difference of A and B ($A \setminus B$) is **not** a subset of C" that means that there is some unspecified object $x$ that is an element of $A \setminus B$ and is **not** an element of $C$. And now unwind what does it mean for $x$ to be an element of $A \setminus B$...

Comment: $x$ is an element of $A$ but not an element of $B$ @MauroALLEGRANZA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us rephrase such statement in terms of logical operators and quantifiers:
\begin{align*}
A - B \subseteq C & \Longleftrightarrow (\forall x\in U)(x\in(A - B)\rightarrow x\in C)\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow (\forall x\in U)(x\in(A\cap B^{c})\rightarrow x\in C)\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow (\forall x\in U)(((x\in A)\wedge(x\not\in B))\rightarrow x\in C)
\end{align*}
Consequently, the denial of such claim is given as follows:

\begin{align*}
A - B\not\subseteq C & \Longleftrightarrow (\exists x\in U)((x\in(A - B))\wedge x\not\in C)\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow (\exists x\in U)((x\in A\cap B^{c})\wedge x\not\in C)\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow (\exists x\in U)((x\in A)\wedge(x\not\in B)\wedge(x\not\in C))
\end{align*}
where $U$ is the universe of discourse, and we have applied the logical identity (and its negation):
\begin{align*}
p\to q \Longleftrightarrow \neg p\vee q
\end{align*}

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: In other words, $(\neg (A-B\subseteq C) )\iff \neg (A\subseteq B\cup C).$

Comment: @DanielWainfleet thanks for the comment :)

Answer (score 0):

Let $X$ and $Y$ be sets. The negation that involves a subset is simply $X \not\subseteq Y$. In this particular example, the negation of $A \setminus B \subseteq C$ is simply $A \setminus B \not\subseteq C$. At this point, we already did the negation. If we wanted to find another form of $A \setminus B \not\subseteq C$, we must consider the set $A \setminus B$. We know that there exist some element $x$, that is $x \in A$,  but $x \not\in B$, but we also know that $x \not\in C$ as well. Therefore, the negation of $A \setminus B \not\subseteq C$ can be simply rewritten to $A \not\subseteq B \cap C$.